# Guardar archivo con saveFileDialog1 en VB 2015

Tags: vb.net, vb

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio que luego de algunos procesos necesito grabar dos archivos. Para ello en un botón "GUARDAR" lo enlacé a un SaveFileDialog donde el operador ingresa el nombre final del archivo. 
Lo que necesito hacer es guardar el archivo como lo pone el operador, y al mismo tiempo necesito grabar el mismo archivo con algunas modificaciones tanto en el contenido como en el nombre de archivo. 
Es decir, si el operador le pone al archivo el nombre: 
"salida202.cut" (los archivos tienen esa extensión) necesito tambien grabar el "salida202-test.cut". 
El primer archivo lo graba perfecto, pero estoy teniendo un problema para generar el segundo archivo. Para eso estoy haciendo para el primer archivo:

```
Dim Archivo As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
        'Agregagamos El Texto
        If IsNothing(txtVCUT.Text) = False Then
            Archivo.WriteLine(txtVCUT.Text)

            'Borra todos los búferes del sistema de escritura actual 
            Archivo.Flush()
            'Cierra el actual objeto StreamWriter 
            Archivo.Close()
        End If
```

Luego hice para el segundo archivo:

```
Dim ArchivoTest As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(saveFileDialog1.FileName) & "-test.cut")

        If IsNothing(txtTEST.Text) = False Then
            ArchivoTest.WriteLine(txtTEST.Text)

            'Borra todos los búferes del sistema de escritura actual 
            ArchivoTest.Flush()
            'Cierra el actual objeto StreamWriter 
            ArchivoTest.Close()
        End If
```

obtengo el nombre del archivo que puso en el SaveFileDialog y le "armo" la ultima parte del archivo agregandole "-test.cut" 
Pues bien... el resultado es que no graba nada de nada... ¿ alguien tiene experiencia con este control, para que pueda darme una mano ?

Comment: ¿El segundo archivo también debe mostrar un cuadro de diálogo "guardar cómo"?

Comment: no, con el primer savefiledialog alcanza... porque el segundo archivo es básicamente lo mismo que el primero pero tiene unas modificaciones... no se por que no me toma el File.CreateText(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(saveFileDialog1.FileName) & "-test.cut")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El archivo con el nombre modificado te lo está guardando en la carpeta donde estás ejecutando el programa, ya que no estás especificando la ruta. `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` sólo trae el nombre del archivo, no su ruta también.

Comment: es verdad !!!... los encontre en el debug del VStudio !!! y como recupero el path del primer archivo ?

Comment: Podés usar `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()` que te trae el directorio donde está el archivo, a eso agregarle el nombre modificado.